# Is it possible to return failed messages to distributor source queue but not worker?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

Is it possible to configure workers (in distributed scenario) to return failed (not processed messaged) to distributors source queue so that another! workers will try to process this message?

Answer (score 1):

When the processing of a message fails, it is moved to the error queue - regardless of whether the endpoint is scaled out across multiple workers.

When you send the message back from the error queue to be reprocessed (whether that's done via the old ReturnToSourceQueue.exe tool or the newer ServicePulse webapp), it is sent back to the "endpoint" - which would be the distributor in the case of a scaled out endpoint, not the specific worker that failed the first time.